# React Native Facebook SDK IOS Event is Not getting fired on Event Manager

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I've got `react-native-fbsdk-next` installed on my project. It's properly installed.

`import { AppEventsLogger } from 'react-native-fbsdk-next';`

```
   facebookSDKInit = () => {
    FBSettings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true);
    FBSettings.initializeSDK();

    AppEventsLogger.setUserData({  //doesnt get registered
      email: 'ertemishakk@gmail.com',
      firstName: 'ishak',
      lastName: 'ertem',
    });

    AppEventsLogger.logPurchase(15, 'USD', { param: 'value' }); //gets registered
    AppEventsLogger.logEvent('Test', { //gets registered
      user: 'ishak',
      email: 'ertemishakk@gmail.com',
    });
  };
```

I call `facebookSDKInit` on `componentDidMount`. Events starts getting registered except when i call setUserData or setUserId, they dont get registered in the events manager.

[image]

Would appreciate any help here. Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution in the meantime?

Comment: seems like Facebook is not showing it on the Event Manager - I've read at few places that user data gets hashed and not shown within the manager. @RaideR